# get satellite count on blackberry api 4.5

Tags: java, blackberry

There is a `BlackberryLocation` class than can give you the count of satellites when you get the location of your phone. The problem is that this class is only available on API 5 and later. Im working with API 4.5 and there is only a class `Location` but I haven't found a method that can give me the count of satellites. I need to know if is possible to get the satellite count on API 4.5 or I have to use API 5 and later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to parse the NMEA String, using your `Location` object:

```
location.getExtraInfo("application/X-jsr179-location-nmea");
```

That method returns a String that, when not null, contains data about the fix. You can tokenize it using the comma character. If the first token is the `"$GPGGA"` value, the eighth token contains the number of satellites.

More info here:
http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/javax/microedition/location/Location.html#getExtraInfo(java.lang.String)